# Emacs: Bernt Hansen's Life in a plaintext - Sample git repo?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

---

Is there a sample git repository which follows Bernt Hansen's Life in a plain text post?

[doc.norang.ca/org-mode.html](http://doc.norang.ca/org-mode.html)

The article is inspiring, and it will be great if we have a ready to use git-repo with all the settings outlined in the article.

Comment: One small nitpick, the page/post is by Bernt Hansen, not by Carsten.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can download the .org source of this web page here: http://doc.norang.ca/org-mode.org

Then you can eval the emacs-lisp code.

Please ask the mailing list for details.